# In Eclipse, how do you rename / refactor all names that occur AFTER the current one

Tags: eclipse, rename

I have a block of about 20 lines of code that heavily uses a specific variable name many times.

I want to copy those lines of code to create another one of these variables, obviously using a different name.

So I click on the variable name in the its declaration of the new block of code. But when I press `ALT + SHIFT + R` to Rename it and all the subsequent ones, Eclipses highlights every single one in the document and slates them for change.

How do I specify that I only want the following variables to be selected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered that what I'm trying to do works if I'm **redeclaring** an earlier variable.

For example if I said:

```
SomeClass something = new SomeClass(Stuff, Stuff);
methodCall1(Something);
something.coolMethod();
```

and wanted to copy and paste that as another object and rename the variable, I would just copy/paste it, and put the pointer in the new `something`,press `ALT + SHIFT + R` and only subsequent `something` would be highlighted for change.

```
SomeClass anotherThing= new SomeClass(Stuff, Stuff);
methodCall1(anotherThing);
anotherThing.coolMethod();
```

I believe this is because I have redeclared the variable, so Eclipse knows not to go before it. However if I was copying a series of method calls made by one object and trying to rename them to work with another object, I couldn't use `ALT + SHIFT + R`

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can select that portion of the text and refactor only within the selected text.

At worst you can copy/paste it into a new file, run the refactor, and then paste it back, but that's rather awkward.

Comment: If I select that portion of text, I can't _also_ position the text indicator inside the variable name

Answer (score 0):

You don't really want a refactoring. Just make a copy and do a find/replace. You can use the Edit menu's Find/Replace option or if you have the results in a search window you can select the files you're interested in, in the search view, right-click and choose "Replace Selected..."

Answer (score 0):

To select a variable automatically then rename, use the following shortcut.

CTRL+ 2 R

Change or modify the variable.

[image]

Fedora 38 Linux

Eclipse Version: 2023-03 (4.27.0)